# Why would I want to use a page query instead of page context?

Tags: gatsby

When creating pages  programmatically in  gatsby-node.js I can pass context to my page component:

```
createPage({
  path: path,
  component: docTemplate,
  context: {}, // additional data can be passed via context
})
```

Seems like I could pass the context needed here to generate my document instead of having to query for it on the individual page again. Any reason why I wouldn't want to do this?

Comment: You could quite easily do that if every page queries for exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably just reserve the page context for data that could be relevant to every page. Each different type of page will most likely have different queries so keep those in the page queries.